# Como pegar um numero no meio de uma string

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou tentando pegar um numero dentro de uma url
`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/35/` este numero pode variar de 1 há 4 digitos. Quero pegar o numero 35 porém com meu atual regex estou pegando o 2 + 35 (235) segue o regex que estou usando:
`/[^\d]/g`
Essa url não possui nenhuma outra variação

Comment: Dependendo da linguagem existe funções mais apropriadas para tratamento de url

Comment: O número precisa ter dois dígitos? Ou precisa estar entre barras? Ora, pelo teu enunciado (número dentro de string), parece correto pegar o 2 e o 35.

Comment: Poderia [edit] e colocar a ferramenta ou linguagem que está usando? E se for uma linguagem (parece ser JavaScript, mas por favor confirme), coloque também o código que usou, pois `[^\d]` pega tudo que **não** é dígito, veja: https://regex101.com/r/GZ0TYq/1 - dito isso, fica a dica do comentário acima: todas as linguagens possuem alguma forma de manipular URL, que é bem melhor do que usar regex

Comment: Seria interessante também colocar todas as regras: o número sempre está no final da URL? São quantos dígitos? Podem ter outros dígitos (além do v2) em outras partes? É pra pegar eles também? etc...

Comment: Sim eu estou usando javascript. E o numero que eu preciso é apenas o 35 posso até tratar aquele dado para tirar o 2 do inicio mas queria economizar linhas de código. o 35 pode varia de números de 1 há até uns 4 dígitos.

Comment: No caso eu preciso apenas do numero final não existe nenhum numero além do final e o v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex abaixo identifica todas as strings compostas por dígitos de `0` a `9` com comprimento entre 1 e 4 caracteres, que estejam cercados por barras (`/`).

```
/(?<=\/)\d{1,4}(?=\/)/g
```

Desta forma não são capturadas os dígitos de partes alfanuméricas, como o `2` de `v2`.

[Verifique online.](https://regex101.com/r/3Wc7l5/1)

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar a função `split` para essa finalidade.

Essa função vai dividir a string em um array, dado um determinado separador.

```
var url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/35/';
var pathArray = url.split('/');
console.log(pathArray[6]);
```